# Where do I put generic library code in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

Quick question: Where should I be putting code that has similar characteristics to the **Controller Utilities Service Class** as described here on this blog post by Benjamin Eberlei (http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/06/27/extending_symfony2__controller_utilities.html)?

For the interim, I've placed it inside: src/ProjectName/Library

**Context**

I've noted the following:

- This logic **does not belong to a specific bundle**, in fact it applies to all bundles one would be creating.
- This logic usually **belongs in an application specific library**, as opposed to being part of a bundle as controllers within bundles would either extend or utilise this library code.

**I found some answers to questions that are similar in theme, but not exactly what I was after**

Based on my research here on SO alone, this question seems to have been trodden to death somewhat, but I think the questions asked previously skirt around what I'm actually after. Regardless, it would seem that I have the following options:

- **Putting these types of extensions in a bundle** - not applicable as the type of functionality I'm developing is essentially extending the framework code.
- **Creating a vendor directory** for the project where all the library code would go - if this is indeed the best practice, then it would essentially mean that I'd have to make the library available via private repo in composer, but that means that I'd have to maintain a separate codebase.
- **Create some sort of pseudo connector bundle** that lives in the src/Company/SomeNamespace - I don't even know if this is at all the way to go, but if it is in keeping with SF best practice, I'll look into it further.

The question, again, for brevity: **Where do I put classes which provide generic, global functionlity in Symfony 2?**

My thanks in advance.

Comment: By global functionality, do you mean global project-specific functionality or global Symfony2 functionality?

Comment: (It's actually an excellent question) Quick hint, you should be able to do this solely with composer. Basically, you can register packages that are PSR-0 compatible, map them to a namespace and should be installed in the vendor folder (the path hierarchy doesn't matter, it's up to you, you can use the other libraries as an example).

Comment: @Dan - by global functionality, I mean functionality that will be available from a global/application scope so that it will be available to all bundles.

Comment: @ThomasPotaire You should turn this into an answer, it's actually the guidance I was looking for. Knowing that this is the accepted way of doing things, I'd happily invest time in working in library code to the vendor directory. Thank you for your help.

Comment: To all those lost in the myriad of options provided by our pragmatic community and have moved on to the later versions of the SF framework. It's in Utils. Do I agree with the convention? No. But I'm keen on and accept the sense of standardisation this provides. Put your library code in src/Utils/YourNamespace/YourClass.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This documentation about [composer repositories](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) is a great reference and the [documentation about packages that don't support Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) should be what you are looking for.

Also I'd like to note the [documentation about VCS](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) which is often used when you need to fork a Bundle and override the original one (I used it quite a few times).

You can do the following - it won't require you to have a packaging system or whatever. You just need to put the package as a zip accessible by your computer using a URL.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "my/package",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/my/package/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-0": {
                        "My\\Package\\": "src/"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

If your package doesn't support PSR-0 then you need to use [the option "classmap"](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) otherwise your package supports PSR-0 you need to use [the option psr-0](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0).

Comment: Thank you. Although, part of this conflicts with the "ignore everything in vendor directory because composer should be able to trash and recreate it at will." philiosophy I've seen around the web, but at this stage, I'd be happy to put up with some not so semantic gitignore rules until we get some more clarity around this concept.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want your third-party libraries to behave that way? It's meant to reduce "copy/pasted" code, easily upgrade your packages around and provide a quick and easy way to install your app. As an alternative I'd put an exception in the `.gitignore` file but composer is definitely the norm.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I guess what's getting at me with this solution is that going this route, I would have to actually create a separate distribution system via packagist, satis or artifact for an application specific library. Let's go back to your initial comment which piqued my interest: "Basically, you can register packages that are PSR-0 compatible, map them to a namespace and should be installed in the vendor folder" - do you have any docs for these?

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thank you Thomas, this definitely helps me along. You've been very generous with your time and I genuinely appreciate that. My thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

After some messing around, while the accepted answer here holds merit, I've decided to create a "Core" bundle which will house all of my projects cross-bundle / application wide dependencies and resources.

This will allow me to have a central place for all assets, related entities and project specific library code.

**Positioned for refactoring**

I've internally reasoned with myself that this is a happy middle ground (perhaps temporary) solution which allows me to get on with development rather than the state of analysis paralysis that I'm in at this present time.

Doing things this way, I can have the flex points to refactor later on to the vendor directory solution.

If you are working on a project and are irked by the somewhat unnatural feel of having your entities and library code scattered around different bundles like I had been, this will be a good solution.

**It does not change the default behaviour of SF2 and Doctrine 2**

I've previously implemented a modification to Symfony 2 Doctrine 2 configuration which allowed me to (rightfully) remove Entities out of the bundle and into a separate, central namespace.

I liked this idea. I used it for a while. The caveat with this approach is that you no longer have the ability to use the Command Line Interface for when you quickly want to create a Doctrine Entity as a Bundle Namespace is required.

I thought it was fine because I needed to change things around anyway, but then I thought:

- "How about the Form objects? where do I put those? In their own directory under /src like Entity is?
- How about the service layer? (not DI, but the actual Service Layer - where the application logic lives)"

Halfway through writing up yet another "where do i put XXXX in Symfony 2" type question (which I'm sure those people following PHP and Symfony2 tags are sick of seeing), I've stopped and put it in a bundle I've called assets bundle, and renamed it to Core bundle.

**The Core Bundle**
This way, it's in a bundle as per the CLI's requirement, it's a lot easier to follow and I can semantically share the contents of this bundle because it contains Core code specific to the application:

- Entities.
- Generic Forms.
- Generic HTML, CSS and JavaScript assets.
- Project Specific library code.
- My Twig extensions also live here.
- Finally, the Service Layer classes and their associated factories go here also.
- If I have any other extensions I want to make to Symfony for this project, I'll be adding them here.

Most importantly, when I get time to actually sit down and work with composer et al, I can refactor this out easily because it all exists in the one place.

So. In a nutshell. To answer my own question: **Where do I put generic library code in Symfony 2?**

I'd put it in a bundle created specifically to store assets, resources and library code which needs to be accessible to multiple bundles using the following recommendations:

- Create a Core bundle.
- Put generic library code here.
- Put all entities here.
- Put generic assets (main.css, reset.css etc) here.
- Put generic forms here.
- Put all service layer classes here.

**Package and install via composer**

Do your research on how to format your file structure to be PSR-0 compliant then, when you're to start using composer:

- Format it to be PSR-0 standards compliant
- Package it up into a zip file and install it via composer (as per @Thomas Potaires editted instructions)

---

**The Application / Project** - Bundles that build the application but rely on the Core Bundle.

---

**Core Bundle** - Extends SF2 at key points, contains shared resources and library code. Because I did not change the way the framework works, the files are where SF2 expects them. This means that I can still use it's generators for Entities.

I won't have a problem with scaffolding / CRUD screens being generated here either as those will be regarded as prototypes, not real application features.

---

**SF2 Layer.** - stays the same, untouched. Extended.

---

Comment: Great read and great contribution! I see now, you wanted to know where  the common core functionalities should be saved; You will quickly find that your CoreBundle will grow significantly over the course of the development of your project which will raise another issue: it's going to be tough to find your way through. As a step forward, you could play with namespaces and do something like `MyBundle\Core\CacheBundle` or `MyBundle\Core\TwigBundle` (which extends SF2 bundle). Your strategy would remain the same but the features would be split up.

Comment: @ThomasPotaire Noted. I'll be coming back to your comment when the time comes to play with bundle architecture. :) Thanks again Thomas.