# Symfony :HOW TO Create Shared -General- (Helper) used in multiple bundles

Tags: php, symfony, helper

I had many helper function -Grouped In Classes - for ( formatting Strings And Dates , URL Helpers  ) that i want to use and share in several bundles , i need to know best practice about where i can put those helpers functions to be shared between bundles.

What came to my mind is to create a helper bundle and use this bundle in the other bundle that i have in my project or use the vendor helper.

So how i can do this and what is the best practice for Creating Shared Helper to be used in multiple bundles.

Please if there is any references i can look at please share it with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found an interesting answer in the following link :
[SO - Generic Lib Code ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911820/where-do-i-put-generic-library-code-in-symfony-2?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If You have universal classes it should be grouped in one bundle ("Helper bundle" as You said) and if it is possible in Your case classes should be defined as services.

If You are using this bundle in more than one project and You want to upgrade that in the future, You should think about moving this bundle to separate repo and define it as a "standalone" bundle (so You can include that in your projects by composer and vendors directory.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to create a PHP library containing those classes. If you really need Symfony integration (eg. DIC configuration), then create bundle that depends on this library.

Every bundle that uses your bundle must list it among it's dependences in composer.json. So it will be installed autocratically every time you install bundle that depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of great examples of libraries out there, that can be imported using composer and used even if they aren't bundles per se, take a look at [Doctrine\Common](https://github.com/doctrine/common) for example.

Regardless, you can also create the bundle as you would any other bundle in Symfony, and structure the code as you see fit. You will notice with many of Doctrine's bundles will make use of the shared library `Doctrine\Common`.

Answer (score 1):

I think Best practice **is** create helper Bundle and create [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) in helper bundle 
Then you can use service in several bundle.

**dummy example**: in your service `Helper.php`

```
 namespace HelperBundle\Services;

class Helper{

    protected $url;

    public function __construct(){

   }

}
```

in `ProfileTreeUserExtension.php` in Dependency Injection folder 
confirm that services configuration file which loaded is `sevices.yml`

```
namespace HelperBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class ProfileTreeLayoutExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

in `service.yml`

```
services:
      helper.service: 
      class: HelperBundle\Services\Helper
```

**Then** you can call HelperService  in several bundles Just

```
$helper = $this->container->get('helper.service');
```

you can also extends Helper class in another service

```
use HelperBundle\Services\Helper;

class AnotherService extends Helper{}
```

**There** good article about [Service Container and Dependency Injection](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-symfony-bundle-configuration-service-container/)